# Filter coefficients in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, speech, synthesizer

I'm learning about signal processing and currently I have to do an speech synthesizer in Matlab. For emulate the resonator system of the mouth I've this transfer function:

R(z) = 1   -   z ^(-1)

Can I implement this system with filter function in Matlab? I don't know how to extract the coeficients "a" and "b"...

Note: y = filter(b, a, x), where x is the input signal that we have to filter.

Thank you all!

Comment: There's no coefficients `a` nor `b` here.

Comment: so, I can't do this with "filter"?

Comment: No idea. You speak about two coefficients that don't show anywhere else in your post. You might as well have said you need coffee and cookies to proceed, I don't see in your post how those are related to your (highly unclear) problem either.

Comment: The coefficients "a" and "b" are the input arguments for the filter function in matlab..   y = filter(b, a, x), where "x" is the input signal that we have to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting the documentation for [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2), you represent a transfer function as a rational function of coefficients such that:

[image]

The desired transfer function you want, `Y(z) / X(z) = R(z)` is equal to:

```
R(z) = 1 - z^{-1}
```

Here `a(1)` is implicitly equal to 1.  Therefore, `b(1) = 1` and `b(2) = -1` referring to the above equation.  All of the coefficients in the denominator are 0 except for `a(1)` which is equal to 1.

As such, `a = 1; b = [1 -1];` and so filtering your signal is simply:

```
a = 1; b = [1 -1];
y = filter(b, a, x);
```

`x` is the signal of interest you want to filter.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But isn't `b(2) = -1`?

Comment: @MatthiasW. NO IT ISN'T.... *quickly corrects*. See? An illusion! (btw thanks for the correction :))

Comment: @Kroka I made a slight error with `b`.  Please check the edit. The theory is of course the same.